# How to determine order/sequence in which products appear in Stripe checkout

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, e-commerce, aws-amplify

In `stripe.redirectToCheckout()` we use [`lineItems`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout#stripe_checkout_redirect_to_checkout-options-lineItems) to list which Products to render; those  Products are items configured in Stripe Dashboard (in either Test mode or Production mode).

I can't seem to find a way to control the order in which products are rendered:

- No change observed if I change **the order of array elements** in `lineItems` (see screenshot).
- No obvious **tool within Stripe Dashboard**, to re-order products e.g. via a "Move up/down" or draggable card.

I thought about trying to change the order by archiving and re-creating Products, but this seems like a hack and would be unsustainable even for 2-3 Products. What do stores do when wanting to A/B test the ordering of Products, or when they have a large number of Products?

It's an awkward one to troubleshoot because "order/ordering", "arrange", "sequence" all have ambiguous meanings...!

[image: checkout.js array and resulting browser view]

Comment: Can you explain what the second two views are? They don't appear to be related to Checkout. I've just verified that both client only and client and server Checkout respects the order of line items when redirected to Checkout. My hunch is that the list of products you're rendering is the result of listing the Products via the API in which case they're always reverse chronological by creation date. The way to determine order in that case would be to store the order indexes in your own DB and then re-order after you retrieve the Products.

Comment: The views are of the checkout page re-rendered after updating the chackout.js file (performed full cache reset & waited 10min before re-rendering). Thanks for verifying the functionality, this helped me realise it wasn't the checkout.js page that was determining render but the GraphQL in my products.js. Once I've figured out the improved query should I post that as an answer below?

Comment: Sure thanks! Anything that helps the community :)

Answer (score 0):

The ordering/sequencing of products using `lineItems` array **does** work (see comment by @v3nkman on OP) but in my case the specific rendered page is not connected to that array on `checkout.js`; it is instead governed by a GraphQL string on `Products.js` and I solved the issue by adding a `sort` field into that as follows:

```
const Products = () => {
  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        query ProductPrices {
          prices: allStripePrice(
            filter: { active: { eq: true } }
            sort: { fields: [created], order: ASC } // new line
          ) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                active
                currency
                unit_amount
                product {
                  id
                  name
                  images
                  description
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `}
      render={({ prices }) => {
        // Group prices by product
        const products = {}
        for (const { node: price } of prices.edges) {
          const product = price.product
          if (!products[product.id]) {
            products[product.id] = product
            products[product.id].prices = []
          }
          products[product.id].prices.push(price)
        }
        return (
          <div style={containerStyles}>
            {Object.keys(products).map(key => (
              <ProductCard key={products[key].id} product={products[key]} />
            ))}
          </div>
        )
      }}
    />
  )
}
```